# NoClassDefFoundError on ClassLoader.defineClass (wrong name)

Tags: java, class, byte, noclassdeffounderror

I have a class file that I am reading the bytes from and defining into a Class object via a reflective call to ClassLoader.defineClass.

The NoClassDefFoundError message that I'm receiving is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/sub/Foo (wrong name: com.foo.sub.Foo)
```

The class file was compiled with the package "com.foo.sub" so the fully qualified name of the class would be "com.foo.sub.Foo"

The call to defineClass:

```
byte[] fileBytes;
//... read file
Method defineClass;
//... initialize and prepare Method for reflective call
Class clazz = defineClass.invoke("com.foo.sub.Foo", fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);
```

The javadocs state (regarding the *name* parameter of *defineClass*): "**name - The expected name of the class, or null if not known, using '.' and not '/' as the separator and without a trailing .class suffix.**"

I don't understand why the exception is being thrown and what the message is supposed to indicate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [that method's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain%29), it will raise `NoClassDefFoundError` if you specify a name (in your case `com.foo.sub.Foo`) that doesn't match the name that the class defines itself as having (inside your `fileBytes`).

To find out the correct name, try something like

```
System.out.println(defineClass.invoke(null, fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length));
```

(which should print something like `class com.foo.sub.Foo`).

Comment: Interestingly, it is printing out the same name that I was previously supplying as an argument. I had not realized that the name parameter could be null... is this acceptable to do or should a name really be supplied?

Comment: @Matt: Re: your first sentence: That's odd, though come to think of it, that's probably what the `com.foo.sub.Foo` in the exception-message was telling us, too. I wonder if there's some subtle difference, like a non-ASCII character or something? Re: your question: It's acceptable. In the documentation that I linked to, it explicitly says to use `null` when the name is "not known". I assume the intended use-case is "not known because we're doing fun dynamic things" rather than "not known because something is going wrong", but I won't tell the class-loader if you don't. :-)

Comment: @Matt: Maybe try `System.out.println(((Class<?>)defineClass.invoke(null, fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length)).getName().equals("com.foo.sub.Foo"))`, just to make absolutely sure that what you're typing matches what it's seeing?